# Equivalance of statement

Tags: logarithms, hash-function

I was studying this paper `Similarity Estimation Techniques from Rounding Algorithms` by `MS Charika`

Inside specifically had this statement.

```
Picking a random hyperplane amounts to choosing a normally
distributed random variable for each dimension. Thus
even representing a hash function in this family could require
a large number of random bits. However, for n vectors, the
hash functions can be chosen by picking O(log^2 n) random
bits, i.e. we can restrict the random hyperplanes to be in
a family of size 2^O(log^2 n)
```

I think it didnt make sense as what it means is that for each n vector, the dimensions would be `log^2 n`. However, the equivalent statement is that the hyperplanes can be in a family of `size 2^O(log^2 n)`

It doesnt seem to make any sense to me. Can someone explain to me why is this statement equals.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are picking
$O(\log^2 n)$ bits,
then the number of values
that can be represented by those bits
is
$2^{O(\log^2 n))}$.

That is,
$m$ bits can represent
$2^m$ values.

Comment: So each vector can be represented as O(log^2 n) bits? If i have 4 vectors, it can be represented by log^2 (4) = 1, It can be represented by 1 bit? It seems a but funny that this is the case